# Expression for a strategy of waiting for a small transgression that can be blown out of proportion?

Tags: phrase-requests

Imagine that Alice is the President of Arstotzka. Alice has a lot of enemies but she's generally an upstanding President so her critics have a hard time building a campaign against her. Instead, the critics are patiently waiting in the shadows until Alice makes a minor mistake - perhaps she misspeaks at a conference or her car driver skips a stop sign. The critics then blow this incident out of proportion and use it to smear Alice before the next election.

What's a word or expression specifically describing the act/strategy of waiting for a small transgression to happen?

Comment: "lying in wait" is a common metaphor.

Comment: "The opponents are watching for (or *on the look out of*) the slightest mistake to step into the breach".

Comment: **Champing/chomping at the bit** is an idiom meaning to eagerly await something, but it can be for something good or bad. ["In addition many government employees are champing at the bit to get the bank in trouble over other types of violations."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Kingdom_of_Lies/so1xDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=champing+at+the+bit+to+find+fault&pg=PT72&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: Broadly, 'waiting to strike' but how is that better than '(a)waiting their chance' or 'biding their time'?